# Can I add a tag to a question when my answer is related to the tag, but the question is not

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

Let's say there is a question with some general tags (Java, REST etc.). In my answer I used a specific technology or library, to solve a problem from the question. Can I add the tag for the thing that I used in the answer, to the question? I assume my answer was accepted.

Answer (score 8):

No. Tags should indicate what the *question* is about, not the possible answers. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> #### What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the **question**.

(emphasis mine)

One of the reasons behind this is that while you might use a specific library (e.g. jQuery) to solve the problem, tagging that *question* with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) might discourage future readers with the same problem, but not wanting to use jQuery (crazy, I know) from reading the question.